# No output for Multiple condition with && operator in for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I've this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    for(int i = 0; (i > 5) && (i < 10); i++)
        // to print the number
        printf("%d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to print numbers from 6-9 but the output is nothing, can anybody help?

Comment: the for loop stops when the condition is false. You should read your favourite book about for loops

Comment: but when i=6 condition will be true then why its not printing

Comment: or better still... use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

The variable i initially set to 0

```
for(i=0;i>5 && i<10;i++)
    ^^^
```

obviously can not be greater than 5.

```
for(i=0;i>5 && i<10;i++)
        ^^^
```

The for loop is executed the following way as for example described in the C Standard (6.8.5.3 The for statement)

> 1 The statement

```
for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
```

> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
> expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
> each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
> scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
> declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
> it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
> the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
> evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
> controlling expression.

So if you need to output values from 6 to 9 inclusively you can write for example

```
for( i = 6; i < 10; i++ )
```

or

```
i = 6;

for ( ; i > 5 && i < 10; i++ )
```

Comment: so if condition become false than 'i' doesn't get incremented, am i right?

Comment: @chand You are right. At first for a given value of i the condition is checked and only when the condition yields true the body of the loop is executed and the control is passed to the expression that increases i.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the value of `i` with 6 rather than 0, so that the conditions will meet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 6; (i > 5) && (i < 10); i++)
        printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

It'll output:

```
6
7
8
9
```